# mysql MATCH in Boolean mode not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have a query that should match in boolean mode that is not working for multiple words and i don't know why. If i search one word is working, when i search multiple words it does't return nothing.

```
q=$_GET['atr'];

$keys = explode(" ",$q);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_products 
            INNER JOIN tbl_products_images_gallery tpig on tpig.id_product=tbl_products.id_product
                             where MATCH ( tbl_products.name) AGAINST ('";
        foreach($keys as $k){
        $sql .= " +$k ";
}
        $sql .="' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) or ";
        $sql .=" MATCH ( tbl_products.slug) AGAINST ('";
        foreach($keys as $k){
        $sql .= " +$k ";
}
        $sql .="' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) "; 

        $sql .=" ORDER BY tbl_products.name ASC ";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
```

edit

i saw where the problem is. If one word has only 2 letters it doesn't find that product. Do you know how to fix this? example: "excursie in delta" if i search for `excursie in` it doesn't find the product, if i search `excursie delta` it finds the product. It seems id does not work for 2 chars.

Comment: did you echo your SQL result at the end of the script to see what it look like? Also, you should probably do `+$k*` to optionally match `$k` within a string, and not just as a full word/

Comment: yes i did var_dump `($stmt->fetchAll());` and it returns `array(0) { }`

Comment: I meant `echo $sql;`

Comment: my guess would be that there is simply no row that matches your query. did you check that there is, in fact, a row which matches all words in your query?

Comment: there are rows because i checked database here is the sql `SELECT * FROM tbl_products INNER JOIN tbl_products_images_gallery tpig on tpig.id_product=tbl_products.id_product where MATCH ( tbl_products.name) AGAINST ('+excursie +in ' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) or MATCH ( tbl_products.slug) AGAINST ('+excursie +in ' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) ORDER BY tbl_products.name ASC`

Comment: could be table problem?